# Как достать программно пользовательские поля Joomla 3.7?

Tags: joomla, joomla3

В Joomla 3.7 имеется возможность добавлять к пользователю дополнительные поля, в которых можно хранить разную информацию.
Вопрос, каким образом можно достать эту информацию программно.
Насколько я понял, в объекте получаемом из метода `JFactory::getUser();` нет этой информации.

Answer (score 1):

Я как-то делал компонент, который выводит профили пользователей, делал так:

В модели получал таким запросом к базе. Вместо `$user_id` - id нужного пользователя, у меня было id просматриваемого профиля, а вам как я понял нужно текущего авторизированного, тогда его получить можно из `getUser()`

```
public function getFields(){  

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query
    ->select(array('a.*', 'b.*'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__fields_values', 'a'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__fields', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('a.field_id') . ')')
    ->where( 'a.item_id=' . $user_id );

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $fields = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $fields;
}
```

Ну и потом можно спокойно пользоваться, где `$field->title` - это название поля,   `$field->value` - значение.

```
 foreach($fields as $field){ 

    echo $field->title;
    echo $field->value;

}
```

Comment: Другими словами, кроме как использование нативного кода, нету специальных методов доступа... ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вы можете получить данные используя `FieldsHelper`:

```
$user_id = JFactory::getUser()->id;

JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
print_r(  FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', ['id'=> $user_id]));
```